# Execution order of the read-host and import-csv cmdlets

Tags: powershell, csv

When I type the following into Powershell:

```
>gc test.csv; read-host "readhost"
```

it gives:

```
 "header"
    "data 1"
    "data 2"
    readhost:
```

(header, data 1, data2 are the correct contents of test.csv, user input return is required after the 'readhost:')

However, when I type:

```
>import-csv test.csv; $line2 = read-host "readhost"
```

It gives:

```
 readhost: #user presses return key
    header
    ------
    data 1
    data 2
```

For some reason that I cannot find online the `read-host` has executed before the `import-csv`.
I've tried to put `read host` in a function and calling that but it did not correct the order.
I read a similar question-answer that suggested piping to `write-host` however this disrupts the csv output format.

Why does the `read-host` executed before the `import-csv` and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?

Comment: Powershell version 5.1

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how, but yes, the |format-table solution given there worked for me. I think I need to swat up on implicit vs. explicit commands in powershell.
Thanks